# How to create a folder in a network different from root using php

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to create a folder in a network using php? I saw many comments and discussions about creating folder. But most of them talking about creating a folder in the root folder using `mkdir()`.

What I need is to create a folder outside that. Lets say I want to create a folder in the ip location `\\192.11.11.111\TEMP\Folder`. But when I tried the following code

`$structure = '\\192.11.11.111\TEMP\Folder';
 mkdir ($structure);`

It is producing an error `Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in C:\MAMP\htdocs\`

I also tried by using a letter instead of ip. 
For Eg: `z:\TEMP\Folder`
But also not able to create folder. Mentioned location has full right to read and write. So issue is not due to permission also.

Can someone help?

Comment: You could achieve the desired functionality with curl PHP lib and setting `CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS` to `true`. But your question is still offtopic on SO, sorry.

Comment: You have to use FTP or sFTP, to create remote files unless the drive is a shared network drive that PHP has access to.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am able to create a folder by doing following way 
`$structure="//192.11.11.111/TEMP/Folder";`
`mkdir($structure, 0, true);`
So the issue was due to the usage of wrong slashes. I hope someone will be beneficial through this thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to create a folder by doing following way

```
$structure="//192.11.11.111/TEMP/Folder"; 
mkdir($structure, 0, true);
```

So the issue was due to the usage of wrong slashes.